# Simplifying $\frac{b^5-a^5-5b^3a^2+5b^2a^3}{b^4+a^4-2a^2b^2}$ into $\frac{b^3-a^3-2a^2b+2ab^2}{a^2+b^2+2ab}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got two algebraic expression, the first should be simplified, with some manipulation I think, to be the second. <s>It's similar to binomial expansion, even though coefficients are a mess</s>.

$$\frac{b^5-a^5-5b^3a^2+5b^2a^3}{b^4+a^4-2a^2b^2} \tag 1$$

$$\frac{b^3-a^3-2a^2b+2ab^2}{a^2+b^2+2ab} \tag 2$$

It's not exactly a problem related to my studies, but something I'm interested in. I remember something similar, when we add/subtract some terms till we got full expansion or so, but I couldn't do anything. Actually, I'm not sure if this problem is correct, so if there's a proof for this problem as invalid one, it's welcome.

Comment: Can you see the denominator of $(1)$ as a perfect square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this problem is in factoring the denominator. We note the following identity:

$$b^4-2a^2b^2+a^4 = (b^2-a^2)^2 = (b-a)^2(b+a)^2 = (b^2+2ab+a^2)(b^2-2ab+a^2)$$

We see that the denominator splits into the goal denominator and another term. We divide the numerator by $b^2-2ab+a^2$ and get the desired numerator. Here is the polynomial division.

$$(b^2-2ab+a^2)(b^3+2ab^2-2a^2b-a^3)\\
=b^5-2ab^4+a^2b^3+2ab^4-4a^2b^3+2a^3b^2-2a^2b^3+4a^3b^2-2a^4b-a^3b^2-2a^4b-a^5\\
=b^5-5b^3a^2+5b^2a^3-a^5$$

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought, although I didn't recognize denominator as anything special. It's quite straightforward, indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I notice is that $b^4 + a^4 -2a^2b^2$ is $(a^2 - b^2)^2$ and $a^2 + b^2 + 2ab= (a+b)^2$.

I can factor $(a^2-b^2)$ as $(a+b)(a-b)$ so

$(a^2 -b^2)^2 = (a-b)^2(a+b)^2$.

And if we have two fractions equal to each other:

$\frac {????????}{(a-b)^2(a+b)^2} = \frac {!!!!!!!!!}{(a+b)^2}$ that has to mean

$\frac {?????????}{(a-b)^2(a+b)^2} = \frac {!!!!!!!!!}{(a+b)^2}= \frac{!!!!!!!!!\cdot (a-b)^2}{(a-b)^2(a+b)^2}$

So if these *are* equal we will have to be able to factor $(a-b)^2$ out the first numerator.

So let's *try* to do that:

$\frac{b^5-a^5-5b^3a^2+5b^2a^3}{b^4+a^4-2a^2b^2}= $

$\frac {(b^5 - a^5)-5(b^3a^2-b^2a^3)}{(b^2 - a^2)^2} = $

$\frac {(b-a)(b^4+b^3a + b^2 a^2+ ba^3 + a^4) - 5b^2a^2(b-a)}{(b-a)^2(b+a)^2}=$ (cancel one of the $(b-a)$ is:

$\frac {b^4 +b^3a + b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4 - 5b^2a^2}{(b-a)(b+a)^2} =$

$\frac {b^4 + b^3a -4b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$ ... now we were *told* that the fractions were equal so that means $b-a$ factors out the numerator even if it isn't obvious.

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+b^3a + b^3a -4b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^3a -4b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)+2b^2a^2 -4b^2a^2 + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)-2b^2a^2  + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)-2ba^2(b-a)-2ba^3  + ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)-2ba^2(b-a)- ba^3 + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)-2ba^2(b-a)- a^3(b-a)-a^4  + a^4}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3(b-a)+2 b^2a(b-a)-2ba^2(b-a)- a^3(b-a)}{(b-a)(b+a)^2}=$

$\frac {b^3 + 2b^2a -2ba^2 - a^3}{(b+a)^2}=$ and that's it, we can rearrange the the terms

$\frac {b^3-a^3-2ba^2 +2b^2a}{b^2 + a^2 + 2ab}$

Comment: That's the hard way to go. Thanks for the detailed steps.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that substituting $a=b$ gives us numerator as zero for both the expressions. Hence, $(a-b)$ is one of the factors.

> $$1.\ -\frac{(a-b)^3(a^2+3ab+b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2}\\ 2.\ -\frac{(a-b)(a^2+3ab+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}$$

Comment: When I tried to solve it, I got this factor but couldn't go forward. This wasn't how I thought about it. Thanks

Comment: @YoussefElkilany Feel free to accept this answer or the answer of Henry Ginn.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler method would be to define $x=\frac{b}{a}$. And then divide the numerator by $a^5$ and denominator by $a^4$, (and taking a 1/a term separately). Then it's easy to see that $x=1$ is a root of both numerator and denominator. So on dividing numerator and denominator by this factor should solve your question. Also even if you didn't spot the $x=1$ as a common factor, just simply performing long division with numerator and denominator will also solve your question.